# staging url not updating even after pushing the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have created a staging instance of my app on heroku.
After commiting the code, when I am doing

```
git push staging master
```

It just says everythign is upto date. I believe it should update the heroku instance on the URL. Nothing gets updated to the staging instance URL.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a heroku restart see if that fixes your problem.

```
heroku restart
```

Also check if the staging points to the heroku git server or any other repo?